# Haskell IO reads an integer n from the user then adds up n integers

Tags: haskell, recursion, io

I'm trying to write a program that reads an integer n from the user, then reads n integers (on separate lines), and ﬁnally display the sum of the n numbers read.

Here is my code so far:

```
addNumbers :: IO ()
addNumbers = do
    putStrLn "Enter a number:"
    num <- getInt
    addNumbers2 num

addNumbers2 :: Int -> IO ()
addNumbers2 num = do
    putStrLn "Enter a number:"
    n <- getInt
    if num == 1 then
        print n
    else do
        print (n + addNumbers2 (num - 1))
```

At the moment it doesn't compile, the error says:

```
Couldn't match expected type `Int' with actual type `IO ()'
In the return type of a call of `addNumbers2'
In the second argument of `(+)', namely `addNumbers2 (num - 1)'
In the first argument of `print', namely
  `(n + addNumbers2 (num - 1))'
```

IO is really confusing me, I'm trying to get an output of:

```
Enter a number:
3
Enter a number:
2
Enter a number:
1
Enter a number:
5
Sum is: 8
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You treated `addNumbers` as if it were an ordinary function, but it's an IO operation, so we can only get numbers out of it inside `do` and with `answer <- addNumbers2`, but also at the moment it doesn't return anything, it just prints it.

I've refactored a little:

```
addNumbers :: IO ()
addNumbers = do
    putStrLn "Enter how many numbers:" -- clearer
    num <- getInt
    sum <- addNumbers2 num  -- use new version to return sum
    print sum               -- print them here
```

and now `addNumbers2` actually adds them and returns them:

```
addNumbers2 :: Int -> IO Int
addNumbers2 num = do
    putStrLn "Enter a number:"
    n <- getInt
    if num == 1 then
        return n      -- pass the number back
    else do
        therest <- addNumbers2 (num - 1) -- get the rest of them
        return (n + therest)             -- add them up
```

That works:

```
addNumbers
Enter how many numbers:
3
Enter a number:
1
Enter a number:
2
Enter a number:
3
6
```

### A better way

`sequence :: Monad m => [m a] -> m [a]` takes a list of actions and runs them all, returning the list of results. If we just make a list full of `getInt`s, `[getInt| _<-[1..num]]` or more consisely, `replicate num getInt` we could do `numbers <- sequence (replicate num getInt)`. There's a shorthand for that in `Control.Monad`, called `replicateM :: Monad m => Int -> m a -> m [a]`

This would be better done like this though:

```
import Control.Monad

addNumbers' = do
    putStrLn "Enter how many numbers:" 
    num <- getInt
    numbers <- replicateM num (putStrLn "Enter a number" >> getInt)
    print (sum numbers)
```

which gives

```
Enter how many numbers:
3
Enter a number
10
Enter a number
20
Enter a number
30
60
```

Comment: Thank you, this is a really neat way to go about this!

Comment: @benharris Here's an even neater way now.

Comment: @AndrewC beats me by just a minute ... Arrrgh!!

Comment: @AndrewC No bad feelings at all .... I just thought: Someone should really tell this guy about replicateM. Had I known you're about to do it, I could just have saved some time.

Answer (score 2):

You can (and should) use combinators available

```
addNumbers2 n = do
    n_numbers <- replicateM n (putStrLn "Number, please: " >> getInt)
    let result = sum n_numbers
    return result
```

The crucial insight is to combine the IO actions

```
 putStrLn "string" :: IO ()
 getInt            :: IO Int
```

to

```
 (putStrLn "Number?" >> getInt) :: IO Int
```

So we have a IO action that asks for input and reads it.

Now, we can use

```
replicateM :: Int -> IO a -> IO [a]
```

and since we pass an IO action that returns `Int`, we get a list of `Int` back.

```
numbers <- replicateM n (putStrLn "Number?" >> getInt)
```

runs the given IO action n times and collects their results.
All that is left is summing up the numbers and returning them in the IO Monad.
Or, if you just want to print the sum, you can also

```
replicateM n (putStrLn "Number?" >> getInt) >>= putStrLn . show . sum
```

Comment: This is certainly a very good way of doing it. I wholeheartedly agree with this great answer!

Answer (score 2):

The following `pipes`-based solution has one tiny advantage over the accepted solution, which is that it will not stack overflow on a large number of lines:

```
import Pipes
import qualified Pipes.Prelude as Pipes

main = do
    numLines <- readLn
    total    <- Pipes.sum (Pipes.replicateM numLines readLn)
    print total
```

Example use:

```
$ ./example
3<Enter>
10<Enter>
20<Enter>
30<Enter>
60
```

Comment: i am trying to understand your code, but fail to see when the input string is converted to the numeric, which can be summed.

Comment: @epsilonhalbe `readLn` does the conversion.  It's equivalent to `fmap read getLine`.